# My .htaccess file not works properly

Tags: .htaccess

I have developed site,I need to run the page as index instead of index.php..i used the .htaccess file too,but unable to achieve a solution..Is there any thing wrong with the code or do i need to do changes..Any helpwould be appreciated..

```
    <Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
order deny,allow
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to remove your `.php` from files

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f   
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you only have to specify `RewriteEngine on` only once. Then make sure of the following:

1. `mod_rewrite` is installed and enabled
2. Make sure your `AllowOverride` directive is not set to `None`. You can find valid options for `AllowOverride` [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).